# Add 3-way switch with regular switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

In one of my greatest moments I decided to move the attic switch from in the attic to downstairs as I'm always forgetting to turn it off and have to go back (yes, I'm a bit lazy).

In any case, I then was like... well what if I go in the attic and forget to turn it on (equally as bad of a scenario).

Attached is a diagram of my current setup. I haven't installed everything yet but the wires and the necessary electrical work downstairs has already been completed. Is there a way to add a 2nd light switch in the attic without modifying the "SW Downstairs" to a 14/3? The LINE is already in the attic. I'm 90% sure the answer is: "No"; but after being in a 90deg attic for a majority of the afternoon my brain isn't functioning at full capacity.

[image]

---

Please note: **everything** is in the attic except "SW Downstairs"

Legend:
SW = Switch; LTS = Lights; G = Ground; B = Hot; W = Neutral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Unless the first switch is already fed with power from somewhere else (which is not the case in your diagram), then you need three (non-grounding) conductors to use a 3-way switch: 1 hot and 2 travelers.

Comment: it can be just wouldn't be from the same circuit and i know that is a no-no. so guess i'm going to be pulling wires again  ;)

Comment: Yep, sorry to confirm your fears!

Comment: Wasn't such a big deal after all. Used the new-old wire to pull the 14/3 back up through the cavity so I didn't have to go fishing again. The result works a treat and I managed to buy exactly the amount of wire I needed without waste which is always nice.